# mysql distinct query not working

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

I have this mysql query for Drupal 6. However it doesn't return distinct nid as it is meant to be. Can someone help identify the bug in my code?

```
    SELECT DISTINCT( n.nid), pg.group_nid, n.title, n.type, n.created, u.uid, u.name, tn.tid     FROM node n 
INNER JOIN users u on u.uid = n.uid 
LEFT JOIN og_primary_group pg ON pg.nid=n.nid 
LEFT JOIN term_node tn ON tn.vid=n.vid 
WHERE n.nid IN ( 
      SELECT DISTINCT (node.nid) 
      FROM node node 
      INNER JOIN og_ancestry og_ancestry ON node.nid=og_ancestry.nid 
      WHERE og_ancestry.group_nid = 134 ) 
        AND n.status<>0 
        AND n.type NOT IN ('issue') 
        AND tn.tid IN (
             SELECT tid FROM term_data WHERE vid=199 AND ( LOWER(name)=LOWER('Announcement') OR LOWER(name)=LOWER('Report') OR LOWER(name)=LOWER('Newsletter') 
     )) ORDER BY n.created DESC
```

The only way I can get distinct nid is adding a groupby clause but that breaks my Drupal pager query.

Comment: DISTINCT is meant to return the DISTINCT row selected, so not a single column as part of the select clause, but the ENTIRE select clause.

Comment: Removing distinct from the main query should work as suggested by @Raghu Chandra, cause you are getting distinct ids and then filtering the records. Now in this case if there are multiple records in User for the same nid you might endup seeing duplicate nid's.

Comment: thanks @astander for clarifying that Distinct only return distinct row. I modified my query by removing the tid field in select statement which caused the duplicate issue. However, I am still puzzled why should we then use DISTNCT(nid) in select statement?

Comment: @astander can you add your comment as answer here? I can then accept it as a valid answer to my question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISTINCT is meant to return the DISTINCT row selected, so not a single column as part of the select clause, but the ENTIRE select clause.

[SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

> The ALL and DISTINCT options specify whether duplicate rows should be
>   returned. ALL (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be
>   returned, including duplicates. DISTINCT specifies removal of
>   duplicate rows from the result set. It is an error to specify both
>   options. DISTINCTROW is a synonym for DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

Remove "Distinct" from first line of your query because already you have distinct id's in where clause. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql , the result with distinct is determined by all selected columns, not by a distincted column, maybe you should write another query to get distinct nid.